# Do cylinder heads on boxer engines wear out evenly?

Tags: cylinder-head, boxer

I know inline engines wear out unevenly on the cylinder heads with one usually egging out more but I don’t know whether or not boxer engines do and I was curious.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm thinking you might be confused? Are you talking about the cylinder head or the cylinder? Cylinder heads don't egg out, but cylinders can. Maybe you can explain a little more what you're asking?

Comment: What other engines have you considered with a similar layout?

Comment: " usually egging out " Please explain

Comment: @Moab probably means ovality - the bore being out of round. Ovality is the engineering term.

Comment: But it is in reference tot he cylinder head.